# How does "migration" out of the Facebook portal work?

Tags: support, migration, mini-site

The Facebook portal requires you to use a Facebook-related tag. I foresee people (especially coming from Google) just adding a Facebook tag to their non-facebook question just to make the warning go away.

Is there a way to kick questions out of the portal and back to just the main site since editors can't just remove the facebook-related tags? You could look up the same question on the main site and then retag it, but there doesn't currently appear to be a quick way to get to the main site version.

Comment: This is a purely theoretical problem.  You need to show this is a problem with real trends in asker behavior (which obviously doesn't exist since Facebook Stack Overflow is less than 1 day old).  Don't try to forsee, wait to inspect actual data.

Comment: @Kevin Really? To me it seems like SE has a lot of design behind it, and you guys actually think about things rather than just hoping they work and aren't abused. Trusting users to never ever get this wrong seems absurd. I presume you have thought about it and have concluded that it won't occur often enough to be worth dealing with besides closures, or perhaps you do have a way of dealing with it, or perhaps it never came up. Either way, *not* trying to foresee this stuff seems like a bad idea, and I'm used to SE's other policies and features that mitigate potential problems before they occur.

Comment: @Matthew - what's worse: completely screwing up a system by heavy handedly fixing a problem that does not (in fact) exist, or a week of the problem existing followed by a fix?  We've always gone with the latter, and it's served us well.  I'm not saying we're ignoring the possibility for a year; I'm saying we might want to actually see the problem happen, you know, more than 0 times.

Comment: @Kevin - I understand the wait-and-see philosophy, but we've seen all the component parts of this behavior before (bad tagging, posting on wrong site, ignoring EULAs and warning dialogs) enough that I don't think I'm just inventing problems. I also realize this won't cause a crisis if it isn't addressed in the first week, I just thought there might be something in place already. Could've been as simple as adding an "edit on SO" link at the bottom, or even dropping the facebook-related-tag requirement for people with edit privileges.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you could just remove the `facebook.` subdomain from the URL when you need to remove the Facebook tag.

[Create a facebook application programmatically](http://facebook.StackOverflow.com/questions/6264080/create-a-facebook-application-programmatically) and [Create a facebook application programmatically](http://StackOverflow.com/questions/6264080/create-a-facebook-application-programmatically) are the same question, so it's easy to hop over to the main site and remove the mini-site restrictions to retag the question.  Admittedly, this is probably more difficult when accessing from a phone, but should still be doable.